# IF and CountIF formula, can you change the 1st value of the duplicate cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Is there a way to set the 1st row of duplicate records to "Parent" instead of "Child"? Or is there another formula method I can use?

- Row 1 - Child
- Row 2 - Child
- Row 3 - Child

TO

- Row 1 - Parent
- Row 2 - Child
- Row 3 - Child

I am using this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A,A2,$B$2:$B,B2,$C$2:$C,C2)>1,"Child","Parent")
```

Comment: whats in your B,C column? share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want something like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(filter(if(countifs(A:A,A:A,ROW(A:A),"<="&row(A:A))>1,A:A,"Parent"),A:A<>""))
```

[image]